# How can I set my constants to a one-time binding?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I currently use '::' syntax to create a one-time binding. Is there an easier way to make all my constants a one-time binding by default? I dont like that I have to add '::' to all my expressions that bind constants.

```
 <div tooltip = "{{::tooltip.NEW_CAR.name}}">new car</div>
```

Comment: If you're worried about too many watchers impacting performance, maybe look at storing your constants outside of angular, in a separate js or json file for instance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Angularjs documentation, the only way to implement one-time binding is through using the "::" notation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression